# Percorrer um vetor multidimensional e capturar o valor existente

Tags: php, matriz

Como percorrer esses vetor `"$_SESSION['gatos1']"` e quando ele achar um valor igual a `"$idt"` ele me retornasse os valores contidos dentro do vetor que contém o valor igual ao `"$idt"`.

```
function buscar($idt){

    for($i = 1; $i < count($_SESSION['gatos2']); $i++){
        for($s = 0; $s < count($_SESSION['gatos1'][$i]); $s++){

            }
```

Comment: Já tentou usar com foreach?

Comment: Sim, sim, mas assim que uso ele não entrega todos os dados que tem no vetor onde tem o valor que é igual ao "$idt".

Comment: Mas como está esse vetor? Seria bom se você mostrasse um exemplo dele.

Comment: De um print_r (json_ encode ($_SESSION)) e coloque a resposta aqui ai fica mais fácil de ajudar.